# Builtin reload() of modified module is not working as I expect it

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have some functions, that write Python code to a file.
In my test I create, import, modify and reload a module, but the reload seems not to work in python2.

#### `test.py`

```
from functions import create_config_file, append_config_list

def test_append_config_list():
    create_config_file()

    import config
    print('Before:')
    print(config.LIST)

    append_config_list(['item2', 'item3'])

    reload(config)
    print('After:')
    print(config.LIST)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    test_append_config_list()
```

#### `functions.py`

```
def create_config_file():
    text = """LIST = [
    'item1',
    'item2',
]
"""

    with open('config.py', 'w') as f:
        f.write(text)


def append_config_list(items):
    import config

    text = "LIST += [\n"
    for item in items:
        if item not in config.LIST:
            text += "    '{}',\n".format(item)
    text += "]\n"

    with open('config.py', 'a') as f:
        f.write(text)
```

### Expected behaviour

```
$ python2 test.py
Before:
['item1', 'item2']
After:
['item1', 'item2', 'item3']
```

### Actual behaviour

```
$ python2 test.py
Before:
['item1', 'item2']
After:
['item1', 'item2']
```

If I use python3 and replace the builtin `reload()` with `importlib.reload()` everything works as expected.

Does anybody has a clue, what I am doing wrong here (besides writing my config in Python code and import it)?

Comment: try execfile primitive

Comment: Yeah, you really shouldn't rely on either generating Python code for a config, nor on `reload()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I mentioned in the comment, you really shouldn't be doing this – a data format such as JSON, YAML, TOML, or if you need more data format support and no human-readability, a Python pickle is better.

Also, you shouldn't be running Python 2 – it's EOL is Soon.

Either way, running with `python2 -v`, to trace imports, led me to figure out what's happening:

```
# ... snip ...
Python 2.7.17 (default, Oct 24 2019, 12:57:47)
# /Users/akx/Desktop/config.pyc has bad mtime
import config # from /Users/akx/Desktop/config.py
# wrote /Users/akx/Desktop/config.pyc
Before:
['item1', 'item2']
# /Users/akx/Desktop/config.pyc matches /Users/akx/Desktop/config.py
import config # precompiled from /Users/akx/Desktop/config.pyc
After:
['item1', 'item2']
# ... snip ...
```

It's using the old precompiled `config.pyc` even if we've modified `config.py`.

Adding `os.utime('config.py', None)` to `touch` the file to tell Python it's actually updated has no effect here – likely because the file system's times don't have enough resolution! The only workaround here is to see if we have a precompiled file and nuke it after editing the `.py` file:

```py
with open('config.py', 'a') as f:
    f.write(text)
if os.path.isfile('config.pyc'):
    os.unlink('config.pyc')
```

... and lo and behold:

```
Python 2.7.17 (default, Oct 24 2019, 12:57:47)
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 11.0.0 (clang-1100.0.33.8)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
# /Users/akx/Desktop/config.pyc has bad mtime
import config # from /Users/akx/Desktop/config.py
# wrote /Users/akx/Desktop/config.pyc
Before:
['item1', 'item2']
LIST += [
    'item3',
]

import config # from /Users/akx/Desktop/config.py
# wrote /Users/akx/Desktop/config.pyc
After:
['item1', 'item2', 'item3']
```

Comment: thank you. this helped. the interpreter did not recognize that the source file was newer than the cache file.